# Custom From Name

Tags: marketing-cloud, send-email

I am trying to configure a custom from name and have adding new sender profiles. When I try to select it from the dropdown menu in send preview, it doesnt come up.

Will appreciate help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a sender profile + a Send Classification using the custom Sender Profile and a delivery profile.

Sometimes, if you have the right permissions, you can override the various profiles despite the send classification.

If you are looking for a dynamic custom form name, you would need to use ampscript and ideally have the field in which the from name are present, in the data extension you are sending to.

Answer (score 0):

You mean org wide email address? Meaning when you want to send an email from Salesforce and you want to choose a different from address besides the current user?

It's at Setup -> Administer -> Email Administration -> Organization-Wide Addresses.

Comment: I believe this is purely a Marketing Cloud question, not Salesforce.com. But perhaps the OP can clarify if this a Connector send within Salesforce or not.

Comment: Ahh, I have a marketing cloud login but not as an admin. :(